# List comprehension expression

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a function which looks like that:

```
  def roulette(self):
    sum = 0
    lst = []
    for x in self.drinkList:
        sum += x.fitness
        lst.append(sum)
    return lst
```

Can it be replaced with list comprehension expression or something more efficient than for loop?

PS: it apperars that if I do random.randrange(0), it raises an exception ValueError: empty range for randrange(). Is there a way to avoid it without using if test?

Comment: Regarding PS: What would you expect a random number between 0 and 0 *exclusive* to be? It's the empty range. You can't randomly choose an element from an empty set.

Comment: The exact formula I use is random.randrange(maxValue - value), where value differs. when maxValue and value are the same, I would like the randrange to return just 0. I thought there is some way (or other method) to do it without handling the exception.

Comment: Not using just `randomrange`, or any other function from `random`. What you ask for is a special case that does something entirely different from random number generation. And I highly doubt there's a function specifically for this purpose. A small check via `if` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually possible to 'peek' at the list being built in a list comprehension.  the outermost list has the name `_[1]`, which of course is not a valid python identifier, so it must be accessed in another way:

```
def roulette(self):
    return [drink.fitness + (locals()['_[1]'][-1] if locals()['_[1]'] else 0) 
            for drink 
            in self.drinkList]
```

But just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*; go with your `for` loop, it looks like exactly what it does, and also doesn't rely on an undocumented python feature.

Comment: That's a damn impressive trick ! But what is the interest of not defining and initializing the list to be returned before populating it before return (as in my answer) ?

Comment: The question was "Can I do *x* with a list comprehension", and my answer is self contained in the list comprehension with no outside dependencies.  presumably this is worthwhile because it's a functionally independent expression, and could be "plonked in" wherever you happen to need a list value.  A function call can do that; but if you are going that far, a function call around a for loop is more readable.

Comment: You mean that if the wrapping inside a function is removed, your list comprehension can take place in a code as a one liner ? Yes, but as I wrote it, I think there's no real interest to do that and that this  trick needs too much complexity to be acceptable. Anyway, I upvote because I learnt the trick ``_[1]``

Comment: -1 This "trick" works only in Python 2.5 and 2.6. A different implementation in 2.7, 3.1, and 3.2 means `locals()` contains no visible name for the temporary list. Result is `KeyError: '_[1]'`

Answer (score 1):

Your `roulette` function is computing the partial sums of the list
of `x.fitness` elements.

You can reach the same result by defining a closure and using `map` on
a generator expression.

```
sum = 0
def partial_sum(x):
  sum += x
  return sum
lst = map(partial_sum, (x.fitness for x in self.drinkList))
```

This is certainly *less readable* than a `for` loop; it could be faster
but you'll have to experiment: `map` is generally faster than `for`,
but function calls are slow.  (Substituting a list comprehension for
the generator expression might speed things up at the expense of
memory.)

Comment: I don't see where the closure is. According to this web page: (http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html) , _"Closures in python are created by function calls"_ and the call records a value in a function, without to be visible. Here I don't see which value is recorded.

Comment: @eyquem I'm using the word _closure_ in the sense described in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)): "a function together with a referencing environment for the non-local variables of that function." The closure is formed by the function `partial_sum` together with its free variable `sum`, which belongs in the definition environment, i.e., the function `roulette`. The fact that the value of `sum` is preserved across calls to `partial_sum` is key to the code fitting the intended purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
[sum(x.fitness for x in self.drinklist[:i+1]) for i in range(len(self.drinklist))]
```

But this would be O(n^2), while yours is O(n).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is more efficient, but this has a list comprehension and less lines:

```
def roulette(self):
    lst = [self.drinkList.pop(0).fitness]
    [ lst.append(x.fitness + lst[-1]) for x in self.drinkList]
    return lst
```

.

### Edit

As nothing authorizes me to modify the list **self.drinkList** , I rewrite:

```
def roulette(self):
    lst = [0]
    [ lst.append(x.fitness + lst[-1]) for x in self.drinkList]
    return lst[1:]
```

Comment: What do you mean ? Explain what is the problem, presently, please.

Comment: Clearly, it is easier and faster to downvote with an unargumented bold turn of phrase than to seriously explain the reason of such a claim whose concision seems to pretend that it is a well-known point of doctine

Comment: for some reason you are *modifying* `self.drinkList`.  It's not clear from the question that this list is in any way disposable.  In addition to that, you are using a list comprehension to execute a function that has a side effect, but not using the generated list.  you are replacing a for loop with a list comprehension only for its loopyness, not its listyness.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy You are perfectly right concerning the modification of **self.drinkList**: I have no clue that I can do that without consequence. I wrote the code so because I wanted to avoid to return lst[1:]. I think that such a modification is truly  what is called 'side effect'

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Concerning the list comprehension, yes I use it to execute a loop in a one liner. I don't see any problem. The list comprehension doesn't execute a function, it executes a method of list **lst**. The side effect of the function **roulette()** isn't due to the list comprehension but was due to the first line in the function, and I corrected. Then, what ??.... At the end of the execution of the list comprehension, there's a None that is "emitted" in the memory. But there is no assignement of this None to an identifier, that's all.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy In fact , I don't know what exactly means "a None is emitted in the memory" and I think that, **None** being a singleton, the None produced by the list comprehension doesn't disappear because of lack of assignement and binding, the singleton None remains untouched. Well, I really don't se where there could be a problem to use a list comprehension for its loopyness and not to build a new list.

Comment: TokenMacGuy said it all. A method is a function. Generally, the expression in the listcomp is used for it side effect., not for its value.

Comment: No. A method isn't a function. _"If you still don’t understand how methods work, a look at the implementation can perhaps clarify matters. When an instance attribute is referenced that isn’t a data attribute, its class is searched. If the (..) class (...) is a function object, a method object is created by PACKING (pointers to) THE INSTANCE object_ **AND** _THE FUNCTION object just found together in an abstract object: THIS_ **IS** _THE METHOD object."_ (http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects)

Comment: You say _Generally_. But I didn't want a general phrase, I wished you to explain the problem _presently_, that is to say in my peculiar use of listcomp here in my answer. Answering like you do doesn't give me more insight in what is called "side effect", which is a notion I don't understand clearly. You're not alone to do so; I've done some researches on Google long before yesterday but I have found no text explaining precisely with good examples what is a side effect and what problem does it create.

Comment: Moreover, it seems to me that in my answer, I use a listcomp for its loopyness as TokenMacGuy said, not for the value of the resulting object that it creates , which is not assigned to an identifier as it would have been the case if I had written ``identif = [ lst.append(x.fitness + lst[-1]) for x in self.drinkList]``. If one does that and ``print identif``, one gets the printing of a list of several None. I formerly wrote it was a None but I was making a mistake, it isn't not None but a collection of None that is created by my code. Nobody corrected me on this point, by the way.

Comment: So, I don't see why the fact that, according to you, a listcomp is generally not used for its value would be a valid argument against my use of a listcomp for the reason of its loopyness.

Comment: This is not a good answer, and your long, ranty comments don't help, but if you _do_ want to do some function that returns `None` for it's side effect, use a _normal loop_ or `any(side_effect(x) for x in iterable)` which doesn't build up a list of `None`s and is still more optimized than a normal loop.